# How to store the output of shell script into variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to Store the output of my shell script below to a variable.

```
echo "05/28/2015" | awk  -F '/' '{ print ($1 <= 12 && $2 <= 31 && match($3, /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/)) ? x="good" : x="bad" }'
```

I tried :

```
x=$("05/28/2015" | awk  -F '/' '{ print ($1 <= 12 && $2 <= 31 && match($3, /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/)) ? x="good" : x="bad" }')

echo $x
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget the `echo`

```
x=$(echo "05/28/2015" | awk  -F '/' '{ print ($1 <= 12 && $2 <= 31 && match($3, /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/)) ? x="good" : x="bad" }')
    ^^^^
echo "$x"
```

**OR**

Use `<<<` to fed input to the awk.

```
$ x=$(awk  -F '/' '{ print ($1 <= 12 && $2 <= 31 && match($3, /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/)) ? x="good" : x="bad" }' <<< "05/28/2015")
$ echo "$x"
good
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ x=$(echo "05/28/2015" | awk -F'/' '{ print ($1 <= 12 && $2 <= 31 && $3 ~ /^[0-9]{4}$/ ? "good" : "bad") }')
$ echo "$x"
good
```

but this may be what you really should use:

```
$ x=$(awk -v date="05/28/2015" 'BEGIN{ split(date,d,"/"); print (d[1] <= 12 && d[2] <= 31 && d[3] ~ /^[0-9]{4}$/ ? "good" : "bad") }' )
$ echo "$x"
good
```